# Can't make Ubuntu 14.04 use ati drivers anymore after last update

Tags: drivers, ati, screen

This if my first post here although I'm an Ubuntu user for more than 1 year (thought not so much experience).

So far I've managed to get things working by simply reading around and applying suggestions but this time I feel I can't really get it working.

A week ago I decided to give Ubuntu 14.04 a try. So I installed it and then installed ATI drivers from the xorg-edgers PPA.

I have to say that my Dell Inspiron 7520 SE with AMD Radem 7730 worked incredibly fast, I just couldn't believe it. About 2 days ago, the automatic updater asked me to update the system, which I did as usual. After that obviously I rebooted but it didn't work anymore, it simply showed a black screen just before login.

I tried dropping to command line but it'd freeze. I finally managed to purge the fglrx via LiveUSB and could login back to my installed Ubuntu 14.04, tried reinstalling the drivers the same way but it won't work anymore, same black screen issue.

Anyone experienced the same thing lately?

Comment: Exactly which driver is this? And is this unity or some other DE?

Comment: Hello Tim! Thanks for you reply. I followed this example on installing the drivers: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ka5gBMlo-zo - as said it worked like a charm until an update a couple of days ago. I'm using Gnome Flashback, I've been using it on ubuntu 12.04 as well and I really like using it customized the way I get best of it.